# Check ENV variables in a loop to see if they were set

Tags: bash

Thought it was a simple thing, but not sure why it got messed up
I'm trying in a `for`-loop to check a few ENV variables and make sure they were set.

This is the current code

```
# Bash 4.2 ( not 4.4 )
# Verify ENV
declare -a env_vars=(
    "HOME",
    "PATH",
    "PYTHONPATH",
    "TESTNONEXISTING"
)
for evar in "${env_vars[@]}"; do
    # Tried: printenv
    # Tried: -v $evar
    # Tried: eval
    if [[ -z "${evar}" ]]; then
        echo
        echo "ERROR: ENV var '$evar' is missing"        
        echo
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

I tried many things suggested here in StackOverflow - but they don't work when used in a loop ( as a string )

An example of something that works, but it's useless ...

```
required_env () {
    ename=$1
    evalue=$2
    
    if [[ -z "$evalue" ]]; then
        echo "ENV variable '$ename' is missing"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Variable exists"
    fi
}

required_env "HOME" $HOME
required_env "PATH" $PATH
etc ...
```

The problem is mainly - how to convert a string - to a real variable inside the "if" - that's what I cannot get ..
Any suggestions ?

Comment: BASH array declaration has no comma in between. Use `declare -a env_vars=( "HOME" "PATH" "PYTHONPATH" "TESTNONEXISTING" )`

Comment: Thanks, the `!` helped, which is very strange already tried it ... thanks ! `if [[ -z "${!evar}" ]]; then`

Comment: Just put `: ${!evar:?ENV variable $evar is missing}` inside the for loop, it will show the error message and stop running the script if the var $evar is null or unset.

Answer (score 0):

`-z` tests if the string is not empty. On the first iteration `evar=HOME`, sp `[[ -z "${evar}" ]]` becomes `[[ -z "HOME" ]]`. You are checking if the *name* of the variable is not empty, not the value of the variable.

You can just check if a variable is set with `-v`.

```
[[ -v "$evar" ]]
```

Note that there is a difference between unset and (set and empty) and (set and not-empty). `-z` checks for unset **or** (set and empty).

> how to convert a string - to a real variable inside the "if"

Use variable indirection.

```
[[ -z "${!evar}" ]]
```

Comment: so I wrote - I tried all of these... it's not working :/